# CSS items on circle make center image larger

Tags: html, css

How can I make the center image 1.25x larger than the outer images? Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xdvjyK). An explainer to the code can be found [here](http://hugogiraudel.com/2013/04/02/items-on-circle/) which I've simplified it.

I've tried adjusting the circle size but it affects all of them.

```
<ul class='circle-container'>
  <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/city'></li>
  <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature'></li>
  <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/abstract'></li>
  <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/cats'></li>
  <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food'></li>
  <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals'></li>
  <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/business'></li>
</ul>

/// Mixin to put items on a circle
/// [1] - Allows children to be absolutely positioned
/// [2] - Allows the mixin to be used on a list
/// [3] - In case box-sizing: border-box has been enabled
/// [4] - Allows any type of direct children to be targeted
/// 
/// @param {Integer} $nb-items - Number or items
/// @param {Length} $circle-size - Container size
/// @param {Length} $item-size - Item size
@mixin distribute-on-circle($nb-items, $circle-size, $item-size) {
  $half-item: ($item-size / 2);
  $half-parent: ($circle-size / 2);

  position: relative; /* 1 */
  width:  $circle-size;
  height: $circle-size;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  list-style: none; /* 2 */
  box-sizing: content-box; /* 3 */

  > * { /* 4 */
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top:  50%;
    left: 50%;
    width:  $item-size;
    height: $item-size;
    margin: -$half-item;
  }

  $angle: (360 / $nb-items);
  $rot: 30;

  @for $i from 1 through $nb-items {
    > :nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
      transform: rotate($rot * 1deg) translate($half-parent) rotate($rot * -1deg);
    }
    $rot: ($rot + $angle);
  }
}

.circle-container {
  @include distribute-on-circle(6, 20em, 6em);
  margin: 5em auto 0;
  border: solid 1px tomato;
}

.circle-container img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.circle-container li:last-child img` to target it, then apply `transform: scale(1.25)`.

```css
.circle-container {
  position: relative;
  /* 1 */
  width: 20em;
  height: 20em;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  list-style: none;
  /* 2 */
  box-sizing: content-box;
  /* 3 */
  margin: 5em auto 0;
  border: solid 1px tomato;
}
.circle-container > * {
  /* 4 */
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 6em;
  height: 6em;
  margin: -3em;
}
.circle-container > :nth-of-type(1) {
  transform: rotate(30deg) translate(10em) rotate(-30deg);
}
.circle-container > :nth-of-type(2) {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(10em) rotate(-90deg);
}
.circle-container > :nth-of-type(3) {
  transform: rotate(150deg) translate(10em) rotate(-150deg);
}
.circle-container > :nth-of-type(4) {
  transform: rotate(210deg) translate(10em) rotate(-210deg);
}
.circle-container > :nth-of-type(5) {
  transform: rotate(270deg) translate(10em) rotate(-270deg);
}
.circle-container > :nth-of-type(6) {
  transform: rotate(330deg) translate(10em) rotate(-330deg);
}

.circle-container img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.circle-container li:last-child img {
  transform: scale(1.25);
}
```

```html
<ul class='circle-container'>
  <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/city'></li>
  <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature'></li>
  <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/abstract'></li>
  <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/cats'></li>
  <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food'></li>
  <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals'></li>
  <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/business'></li>
</ul>
```